# Return Static date using SQL Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a situation where i need to return a date.Here for this function i will be supplying month number and i need to return result like "3/13/2012".

```
declare @date varchar(20)
select @date=datepart(month,getdate())+'/13/'+datepart(year,getdate())
return @date(@date)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for ya.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnStaticDate(@month varchar(2))
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @year VARCHAR(4)
SET @year = DATEPART(year, GETDATE())

RETURN CONVERT(DATETIME, @year + '-' + @month + '-' + '13')

END
```

Comment: @vijayenderpailla - no problem, glad I could help. BTW... I think you need to accept one of the answers to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution which i have used for one of my project.

created a store procedure with input parameter of month

```
declare @mon varchar(2) 
set @mon = '3' 
select CONVERT(varchar, @mon + '/13/' + convert(varchar, datepart(year, getdate())), 111 )
```

execute the above lines in SQL server you will get the result.

test by changing the `@mon` value in set statement.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

conversion error it gives

```
 declare @date varchar(20)
select  @date=convert(varchar(2),datepart(month,getdate()))+'/13/'+convert(varchar(4),datepart(year,ge tdate()))
print (@date)
```